# SSRS: How to create pivot table result without blank cells?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

### Test Data

For example, I have test data as below.

```
|Student    |Class     |Score|
|A          |English   |90   |
|B          |Computer  |78   |
|B          |Math      |88   |
|C          |Math      |55   |
|C          |Computer  |86   |
|C          |English   |64   |
```

You could create test data as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
([Student] varchar(1), [Class] varchar(8), [Score] int)
;

INSERT INTO Test
([Student], [Class], [Score])
VALUES
('A', 'English', 90),
('B', 'Computer', 78),
('B', 'Math', 88),
('C', 'Math', 55),
('C', 'Computer', 86),
('C', 'English', 64)
;
```

In SSRS, create a new report with a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM Test
```

### Expected result

Now, I want to show the result as below in SSRS. So the data is group by students and list all the class & scores the student gets. Is that possible?

```
|      A         |      B         |      C         |
|Class     |Score|Class     |Score|Class     |Score|
|English   |90   |Computer  |78   |Math      |55   |
                 |Math      |88   |Computer  |86   |
                                  |English   |64   |
```

### Current status

I was able to create result as below by adding a column group on Student column but not sure what's the next.

Here is the test config I used.

[image: SSRS test settings]

```
|      A         |      B         |      C         |
|Class     |Score|Class     |Score|Class     |Score|
|English   |90   |          |     |          |     |
                 |Computer  |78   |          |     |
                 |Math      |88   |          |     |
                                  |Math      |55   |
                                  |Computer  |86   |
                                  |English   |64   |
```

Comment: Please, add more information on what you've exctly done.

Comment: Is that clear now? The result needs to be grouped by student column.

Comment: have you done row grouping by class?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that it's still not clear. Which query do you use? Which controls are there in the report and how are they configured. The data structure is clear, but not hwe need to see how you implement it.

Comment: @JotaBe I am not sure how to explain it more... All the things I talked as simple steps for SSRS.

Comment: @hemanth Yes, I tried. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I fixed myself.

First, add a new dataset with this query. It has a row number `rn`, partition by student.

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY Class) AS rn FROM Test
```

Then, add a column group for `Student`, a row group for `rn` with group header. In the row group header, set them with fx `=Min(Fields!Class.Value)` & `=Min(Fields!Score.Value)`. Clear the `rn` cells as I don't want to display it here.

The last important step here is to hide the details rows. And here is the result.

[image: SSRS setup]
[image: SSRS result]